# How does IP deal with platform conflicts?

Tags: networking, ip

Another question for a test I'm studying for. My Google-fu is weak or something.

There is no requirement that a communicating client and server need to be on the same platform. However, different platforms (hardware and OS) may interpret data differently (bytes in a word are ordered by lowest to highest order or by highest to lowest). How do the Internet Protocols deal with this problem?

Comment: Everything is typically send in "network order" (big endian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All protocols that are expected to be used across different environments specify byte order, text encoding and other contracts explicitly*.

*) sometimes "explicitly" means "I wrote it that way and all you to follow" instead of thinking what would be more convenient way for most of the people.

Comment: In particular, the IP-based protocols define a "network order", which is big-endian. All portable data is expected to be in network order.